# Creating an array of arrays filled with 'false'

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array of arrays which are all filled with `false` in JavaScript. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

My current code is this:

```
var fieldFilled = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fieldFilled.push([]);
            
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        fieldFilled[j].push(false);
    }
}
```

I don't understand this error because it seems like `fieldFilled` is defined.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `fieldFilled[j]` should be `fieldFilled[i]`

Comment: @Barmar yes, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Check out Array.fill(). Ex. `Array(10).fill(false)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the functional approach:

```js
const a = new Array(10).fill(0).map(e => new Array(10).fill(!1));

console.log(a)
```